# Parallelizing a large dynamic program

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, dynamic-programming, work-stealing

I have a high-performance dynamic program in C++ whose results are placed in an M × N table, which is roughly on the order of 2000 rows × 30000 columns.
Each entry (*r*, *c*) depends on a few of the rows in a few other columns in the table.

The most obvious way to parallelize the computation of row *r* across *P* processors is to **statically** partition the data: i.e., have processor *p* compute the entries (r, *p* + *k* *P*) for all valid *k*.

However, the entries for different columns take a somewhat different amount of time to compute (e.g., one might take five times as long as the other), so I would like to partition the data **dynamically** to achieve better performance, by avoiding the stalling of CPUs that finish early and having them instead steal work from CPUs that are still catching up.

One way to approach this is to keep an atomic global counter that specifies the number of columns already computed, and to increase it each time a CPU needs more work.
However, this forces all CPUs to access the *same* global counter after computing *every* entry in the table -- i.e., it serializes the program to some extent. Since computing each entry is more or less a quick process, this is somewhat undesirable.

So, my question is:
Is there a way to perform this dynamic partitioning in a more scalable fashion (i.e. without having to access a single global counter after computing every entry)?

Comment: Have you thought about using the GPU. CUDA springs to mind

Comment: @EdHeal: I have, but (1) I don't really know GPU programming, and (2) my understanding is that a GPU isn't well-suited for computations like this, where the amount of computation varies depending on other factors (e.g. where the number of dependencies varies based on the row and column).

Comment: "after computing *every* entry" - why don't you fix the granularity? allocate tasks in larger chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a second array for the new values. If so, it sounds like the looping constructs from either TBB or Cilk Plus would do. Both use workstealing to apportion the work among the available processors and when one processor runs out of work it will steal work from processors who have work available. This evens out the "chunkiness" of the data.

To use Cilk, you'll need a commpiler that supports Cilk Plus. Both GCC 4.9 and the Intel compiler support it. Typically you'd write something like:

```
cilk_for (int x = 0; x < XMAX; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < YMAX; y++) {
        perform-the-calculation;
    }
}
```

TBB's constructs are similar.

Another approach is to "tile" the calculation in a cache-oblivious way. That is, you implement your own divide-and-conquer algorithm that will break the calculation into chunks that will be cache-efficient. See http://www.1024cores.net/home/parallel-computing/cache-oblivious-algorithms/implementation for more information on cache-oblivious algorithms.

Barry